# Type constraints being interpreted strangely

Tags: c#, types

I have two classes.  I would like one of them to accept two type parameters representing the type of the model, and the type of the result.

I have done this by using type constraints to say that `TResult` must either be `TModel` or an `IEnumerable<TModel>`.  So far so good.  Now, to avoid having to supply two type parameters every single time, I wanted to create a second class that takes just one type parameter, and inherits the other class with both type parameters supplied.  The classes are shown here:

```
public class QueryBase<TResult, TModel>
    where TModel : ModelBase
    where TResult : TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>
{

}

public class QueryBase<TModel> : QueryBase<TModel, TModel>
    where TModel : ModelBase
{

}
```

The problem is, when I try to do this I get an error from Visual Studio saying the following:

> The type 'TResult' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the
>   generic type or method 'VTDI.Queries.QueryBase'. There
>   is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TResult' to
>   'TModel'.

My question is: what's going wrong here?  I would have thought my type constraints could guarantee conversion is possible, but Visual Studio doesn't seem to agree.

Comment: `where TResult : TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>` that means `TResult` must be `TModel` **and** an `IEnumerable<TModel>`.

Comment: @PetSerAl you're right, in that case I wonder why the type constraint itself was accepted as valid, since it's contradictory, right?

Comment: You can't constrain a type parameter to be either one thing or another. If you wrote a method that accessed a property of `TModel`, how would the compiler know which class you meant?

Comment: It's not contradictory for a class to implement `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is itself, although it would be strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constraint actually means that `TResult` must derive from **both** `TModel` and `IEnumerable<TModel>`.

```
where TResult : TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>
```

The problem is in the second class `QueryBase<TModel>`. Where the constraint on the second type is just:

```
where TModel : ModelBase
```

This constraint is less restrictive than the one on the base class `QueryBase<TResult, TModel>`.

```
where TResult : TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>
```

If you changed the constraint on the second class to be as restrictive as the first class, then you will be able to compile:

```
public class QueryBase<TModel> : QueryBase<TModel, TModel>
    where TModel : ModelBase, IEnumerable<TModel>
```

But I doubt this is what tyou really want to do. It seems like you may have your inheritance backwards. Could you accomplish what you are trying to do by having `QueryBase<TModel>` as the base class, then make `QueryBase<TResult, TModel>` inherit from that?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class QueryBase<TModel> : QueryBase<TModel, TModel>
    where TModel : ModelBase
```

By substituting the type parameters into the super type you get:

```
public class QueryBase
    where (TModel : ModelBase) => (TModel : ModelBase)
    where (TModel : ModelBase) => (TModel : TModel, IEnumerable<TModel>)
```

I am fudging the syntax to make the point. With `x => y` I am saying that `y` must follow from the assumption `x`. The problem is that you cannot conclude `TModel : IEnumerable<TModel>` from `TModel : ModelBase`. A possible fix is to add this constraint to the subtype.

```
public class QueryBase<TModel> : QueryBase<TModel, TModel>
    where TModel : ModelBase, IEnumerable<TModel>
```